# Counting Points on a Plane Curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I want to find the number of points of $\displaystyle \mathcal{C}_{h} \cap A^{2}( F_{q})$, (char(F) is not equal to 2,3), where $\displaystyle h$ is a rational function defined as $\displaystyle h( x) =\frac{x^{2} +d}{x^{3} +ax^{2} +bx+c}$

The curve associated to the above rational function is defined as $\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
G( X,Y) ;h( X) -h( Y) =0\\
( X-Y)\left( X^{2} Y^{2} +d\left( X^{2} +Y^{2}\right) +( d-b) XY+( ad-c)( X+Y) +bd\right) =0
\end{array}$

For this I first need to calculate the number $\displaystyle R_{q}$ of $\displaystyle F_{q}$-points on the projective closure of $\displaystyle \mathcal{D} ,$ where $\displaystyle \mathcal{D}$ is defined by $\displaystyle F( X,Y) =X^{2} Y^{2} +d\left( X^{2} +Y^{2}\right) +( d-b) XY+( ad-c)( X+Y) +bd=0$.

Can anyone help how to count the number of points of $\displaystyle \mathcal{C}_{h} \cap A^{2}( F_{q})$

Comment: This is (generically) a curve of genus 1, so there typically won't be an exact formula, but rather a Hasse-Weil bound.